# DateTimePicker not allowing times other than hour

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a datetimepicker from this website https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

I am trying to use the picker for appointments. It works when I just pick the hour but when I pick any other time, say 14:30, it goes in as that time but the nearest hour is highlighted so it is confusing to the user.

```
$('#DateOfAppointment').datetimepicker({
  format: 'd/m/Y H:i',
  minDate: 0,
  inline: true,
  allowTimes: ['9:00', '9:30', '15:00', '17:00', '17:05', '17:20', '19:00', '20:00']
});
```

Is there anyway to fix this or is another plugin needed?

**PS: **I need to have set times.

Comment: It may help to see more of your code as there's not enough context in the JS you've shown to diagnose the problem you describe

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thats literally all I have on my razor page. I can show my whole page but it would just be pointless

Comment: I've recreated the logic here: https://jsfiddle.net/aon61dta/1/ although I'm still not sure what the issue is as it appears to work fine

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thats interesting. I don't know whats wrong with it. Only thing I can think of is it may something in the javascript file

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: I think something related to timezone. But I am not sure